# java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: in RC6 as well as RC2

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I'm new to security, and I tried a lot to remove the exception (below the code). Both the RC2 and RC6 ciphers are giving this exception. The input should be a 128 bit `String` and a key of 128 bits, the output should be 128 bits cipher text.

```
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.util.*;

public class RC2Encrypt
{
    public static void main(String args []) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter PlainTextString:");
        String input=s.nextLine();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter 16 digit key:");
        String strPassword=s.nextLine();

        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(strPassword.getBytes(), "RC2");
        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(strPassword.getBytes());
        Cipher cipher =  Cipher.getInstance("RC2");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());

        String b1 = new String(encrypted);
        System.out.println("Original string: " + input);
        System.out.println("Encrypted string: " + b1);
    }
}
```

---

This will generate the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Wrong IV    length: must be 8 bytes long
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.a(DashoA13*..)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RC2Cipher.engineInit(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at RC2Encrypt.main(RC2Encrypt.java:40)
```

Comment: i tried to change parameters and i used keyGenerator also but same error was there, and during execution i saw this exception

Comment: You haven't shown us the exception. No attempt should be made to answer this question until you do.

Comment: @GregS Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Wrong IV    length: must be 8 bytes long
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.a(DashoA13*..)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RC2Cipher.engineInit(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at RC2Encrypt.main(RC2Encrypt.java:40)

Comment: As you are new here I am a bit lenient regarding the question, but please try and write full sentences in your question. Use separate code blocks for the exception and code, and put the actual question in front of them. Please don't let us do the spelling for you. Make sure you look up previously asked questions. At least 25% of the questions here are about encoding or character-encoding at some point.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the poster is seriously messing things up here. The stack trace posted in the OP is a result of using the code from _my_ answer with the wrong IV. The code in the OP however results in an `Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Illegal parameters` because the line `Cipher.getInstance("RC2");` is incorrect (hence my suggestion to use 3DES)

Comment: @praseodym You should really reread the comments. The `RC2Cipher.engineInit` part in the stack should be self explanatory. Besides that if there is any provider that supplies the `"RC2"` algorithm, then there may be nothing wrong with `Cipher.getInstance("RC2")`, code wise. The user also indicated that he needed to do this for multiple ciphers in a response to *your* answer, so this is probably an assignment of some kind. Don't forget to use @owlstead if the question is directed to me.

Comment: @owlstead I came to my conclusion above after running the OP code myself; I really can't reproduce the stack trace from the OP. You are right about the `RC2Cipher.engineInit` though, I missed that.

Comment: guys sorry about formatting, and thank u for ur response...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code.

The most important one is that you confuse characters and bytes. You will have to know about [character-encoding](/questions/tagged/character-encoding) - which is about encoding text in binary and back - and [encoding](/questions/tagged/encoding) - which is about encoding binary as readable text.

If you expect 8 bytes encoded by 16 characters then this implies that you need to perform hexadecimal decoding (which uses two characters for each byte). The best way of doing that is to use the Apache common codec library or the Bouncy Castle libraries. I would suggest the latter because it contains many more encryption algorithms - including RC6. The best way is to use the Bouncy Castle provider for the cryptographic functionality.

OK, so that solved the part with the key and IV, now for the plain text. The plain text must be binary encoded. Unfortunately you are now using the platform default character set. This means you will run into compatibility issues if you want to exchange it with another system (or other application, even on your own PC, if it uses another character set). To remove this issue you should specify an encoding yourself, e.g. use `String.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))` or on Java 7 onward `String.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`. Do the same for the constructor.

Furthermore, you really should not be using the same bytes for the key and IV. The IV is used to encrypt several ciphertext with the same key, without introducing security vulnerabilities. E.g. an attacker could know that the first, not so secret ciphertext contains the word "yes". Then the next cipherblock comes along and contains the exact same bytes; obviously the sender has send the word "yes" again. If the IV was changed the attacker would see an entirely different cipher text - although it would still be 3 bytes long for stream ciphers.

Finally, the key and IV should be randomly generated - possibly at some time in the past. If a password is required instead of a key, you should use a PBKDF (password based key derivation function) as a sub-optimal replacement. But I think that might be a more advanced topic.

Comment: The _real_ error in the OP's code is in `Cipher.getInstance("RC2");`, so not even related to character encoding (although, sure, if the cipher is initialised there will be problems with encoding). It's a mess.

Comment: @praseodym no, that's not correct, there is nothing wrong programming wise with `Cipher.getInstance("RC2")`. The fact that it does not generate any exception should show that fact to be true.

Answer (score 1):

I would certainly recommend a different algorithm, since RC2 is very weak. As far as I know there is no RC6 support bundled with the JRE.

You could use TDES as follows:

```
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
```

Note that you do need to specify an [initialisation vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) that consists of random bytes, and certainly *not* your key (like in your code). Also, TDES needs 128- or 192-bit keys.

Comment: thanx for help but i have to show the cipher generated by AES,DES,3DES,blowfish,RC2 & RC6 thats y i m asking for RC6

Comment: this above code for 3DES is also giving same exception.  Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Wrong IV length: must be 8 bytes long
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.a(DashoA13*..)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESedeCipher.engineInit(DashoA13*..)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
        at TripleDESTestEncrypt.main(TripleDESTestEncrypt.java:50)

Comment: @owlstead the stack trace in the OP was added after my answer; user1972920 like my answers says you need an IV; the stack trace in the comment above clearly states that your IV has the wrong length.

Comment: @owlstead Thanks, but why 'TDES' instead of '3DES'? Afaik 'TDES' is not very widely used at all.

Comment: Well, officially the algorithm is called TDEA, but even NIST referred to it as TDES. 3DES is never mentioned in the specs, and `3des` is not a valid identifier for most languages either :)

Comment: Wikipedia only mentions '3DES' (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) and even NIST only seems to call it 'TDEA', but it sure is confusing to have so many names :)

Comment: From that page: "While none of the standards that define the algorithm use the term "3DES", this term is used by some vendors, users, and cryptographers.[5][6][7]
[edit]"